# jquery format output with 2 number and with komma not with point

Tags: jquery, format, numbers

i have this script and it works. when radio button value is "" than 0 eur and when != value "" than 3.57.

```
<script>
$(":radio").on("change", function(){
    var total = 0;
    $(":radio:checked").each(function(){
    if(this.value != 0){
        total += Number(3.57);
        }
    });
    
    $("#total").text(total);
  
   
    
    
});
</script>
```

this is the html output:

```
<span id="total" style="color: red;">0</span>
```

but how can i output it in format X,XX? i get X.XXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: to make it short it's `total.toString().replace('.', ',');` but your code is very misleading because you are looping all radio buttons like if they belonged to different groups while radios of the same group are mutually checked and it would be enough to do `$(this).val() != '0'` instead of checking all the radio in the document

Comment: thank you. you mean instead of "$("#total").text(total);" i should use "total.toString().replace('.', ',');"?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very very simple solution that will take the `Number` and will call on it the function `toFixed(2)` to have a string representation with 2 fixed digits after the decimal separator (also when not needed, eg.: `1,00`) and will replace the decimal separator with comma.

I added some extra things like labels, styles and better dealt with the currently changed value inside the event handler instead of fetching all the radio buttons existing in the page. Anyway this details was not clearly covered in the question so I made some assumptions.

***edit:***
After reading your comment I also added a select element that will behave like the radio buttons, showing the result in the output target as the radio buttons did on change.

```js
$(":radio").on("change", function() {
  //target value is the value of the element triggering the event
  //!warning.. it gets fetched as string (if you meant to have it as number you shoud use parseInt or parseFloat)
  const targetValue = $(this).val();
  showOutput(targetValue);
});

$("select").on("change", function() {
  //target value is the value of the element triggering the event
  //!warning.. it gets fetched as string (if you meant to have it as number you shoud use parseInt or parseFloat)
  const targetValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();  
  showOutput(targetValue);
});


function showOutput(value){
  var total = 0;

  //if the currently changing radio option has value != 0 (only the first radio option has value == 0 and they all belong to the same group) 
  if ( value != 0 ){
    
    total += Number(3.574545);
  }  

  //here it serializes the number to string using 2 digits after decimal separator and will replace that with comma
  totalToString = total.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
  
  //updates the content in #total with the computed totalToString
  $("#total").text(totalToString);

}
```

```css
input[type=radio]{  
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="v0">Value: 0</label>
<input id="v0" type="radio" name="group" value="0">
<br>

<label for="v1">Value: 1</label>
<input id="v1" type="radio" name="group" value="1">
<br>

<label for="v2">Value: 2</label>
<input id="v2" type="radio" name="group" value="2">
<br>

<select>
  <option value="0">Value: 0</option>
  <option value="1">Value: 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value: 2</option>
</select>

<br>
<span id="total" style="color: red;">0</span>
```

Comment: this was quite an obvious q/a.. anyway if you think the problem is over, put the efforts to mark the answer as accepted so that it doesn't remain open

Comment: can i use this even when i have select option inputs?

Comment: I updated the answer adding the dropdown scenario with the same logics